# Type (Dynamic binding) in java

Tags: java, dynamic, binding

Vegetable Class

```
  public class Vegetable {
     public void cook() {
     System.out.println("cook veg");
     }
     public static void eat(Vegetable veg) {
     System.out.println("eat veg");
     }
     public static void eat(Bean bean) {
     System.out.println("eat bean");
     }
     public void pick(Vegetable veg) {
     System.out.println("pick 1");
     }
 public void pick(Bean bean) {
 System.out.println("pick 2");
 }
} // end class Vegetable
```

Bean Class

```
public class Bean extends Vegetable {
 public void cook() {
 System.out.println("cook bean");
 }
 public String name() {
 return "bean";
 }
} // end class Bean
```

Lentil Class

```
public class Lentil extends Bean {
 public String name() {
 return super.name()+" lentil";
 }
 public void pick(Vegetable veg) {
 System.out.println("pick 3");
 }
} // end class Lentil
```

Testing Class

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Vegetable v = new Vegetable();
    Bean b = new Bean();
    Lentil len = new Lentil();
    Vegetable vb = new Bean();
    System.out.println(v.pick(len));
    System.out.println(b.pick(len));
    System.out.println(len.pick(len));
    System.out.println(Vegetable.eat(len));
    }
}
```

I really don't understand why these work. For example v.pick(len). len is declared as a Lentil and is of type Lentil. So how will this work if there is no function that takes a Lentil? Same goes for all of the other functions, I really don't understand how Lentil works.

Comment: Lentil extends Bean, and there's a function that takes a Bean. Same for Vegetable.

Comment: Also, this isn't dynamic binding.

Comment: But even though it extends bean, its not declared as bean. Doesn't it need to be declared as bean for it to work?

Comment: What is `v` `b` `len` in your `main` method?

Comment: Oh sorry forgot about that. Added it in!

Comment: "*So how will this work if there is no function that takes a Lentil?*" but there is a method which can handle any `Bean` so since `Lentil` is-a Bean this method was used. There was also method which could handle `Vegetable` bur since more detailed match for `Lentil` is `Bean` than `Vegetable` `pick(Bean bean)` was used.

Comment: So if the method took bean, and we inputed a vegetable, that wouldn't work right? Because we wouldn't be certain that the vegetable is a lentil.

Comment: Yes if method expects `Been` we can't pass `Vegetable` to it, because been may have some additional methods which Vegetable doesn't have. Lets say that we have `class Foo{ } class Bar extends Foo{ void baz(){}}`, and `Bar b = new Foo()` is valid. In that case compiler should also accept code like `b.baz()`, but what should happen when executing this code (`Foo` doesn't have `baz()` method)? Such code would cause error. That is why we can't use reference of child class to store instance of parent class.